# Clear Window in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a tkinter GUI that, when opened, is an empty widget with a menu bar on top. Clicking on the options on the menu causes for text boxes, more buttons and more menus to appear in the widget. My problem is that everything overlaps.
I need an easy way to delete everything that is currently there, like a "clear window" option.
I've tried packing everything into a frame and then destroying a frame but, for some reason, it's not working.
Any suggestions? 
Ideally, I would make something that checks to see if there is anything (button, text box, menu) in a designated space, and it would delete it all before creating the new widget attributes.

Comment: Only one suggestion: show your code.

Comment: I can't @furas - company guidelines.

Comment: "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem" - [Stackoverflow guidelines (How do I ask a good question?)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Do you use `grid()`, `pack()` or `place()` ? Normally I would use `Frame` with widgets and add this frame to main window with `Frame.grid()` or `Frame.pack()` and then I would use `Frame.grid_forget()` or `Frame.pack_forget()` to hide frame with all widgets. This way I don't have to check anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem I was having was fixed by creating a new frame within each function and having the code destroy any previously existing frames with `Frame.destroy()`. 
My second problem, where widgets within my frame were not, appearing was being caused by how Tkinter frames automatically resize to fit the original widgets. Therefore, when I added widgets to the frame, the frame remained the size of the first widget and didn't show the new buttons. I used `frame.pack_propagate(0)` to force the frame to remain the specified size.